# Php: Login not working on hosting the file to a web server. Works well on local host

Tags: php, post, host

My login modal uses the method post and send the variables to another file (in a different folder) which works well on my localhost but throws the following error on hosting:

> HTTP 500 error That’s odd... the website can’t display this page

If I reload this page, I am redirected back to the homepage without logging in (http://.../index.php?Loginn=error3).

LOGIN FILE:
  <

```
form class="modal-contents animate" action="Fon/LogInFile.php" method="POST">
        <span onclick="document.getElementById('id').style.display='none'" class="closes" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
        <div class="container1">
      <h2> Log In</h2>
          <tr><b> Email</b>
          <input type="text" placeholder="email" name="username" required></td></tr> <br>
          <tr style=""><td ><b>Password</b>
              <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" id="Pass" name="pswdd"; required></td></tr>
             <tr> <span class="psw">Forgot <a href="#"> password?</a></span></tr> <br>

      <tr><td><button type="submit" id= "LogInBut">Login</button></td></tr> 
        <tr><td><button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none'" id="CancelBut">Cancel</button> </td></tr>
      </td></tr><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Remember me</td></tr>
```

**Fon/LogInFile.php :**

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST") {
include '../databaseconnection.php';    
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['pswdd']);

            //Error Handlers 

                    $_SESSION['user']=$username;
                    $_SESSION['password']=$password;
        header("Location: ../index.php?loginss=successful");
                    exit();
                }
else{
        header("Location: ../index.php?Loginn=error3");
        exit();
}
}
```

Comment: Debug by echoing value of $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] .

Comment: Please tell me how? I am quite at loss

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'; // To check the value
echo isset($_POST["submit"]) 
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
include '../databaseconnection.php';    
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['pswdd']);

            //Error Handlers 

                    $_SESSION['user']=$username;
                    $_SESSION['password']=$password;
        //header("Location: ../index.php?loginss=successful");
                  //  exit();
                }
else{
        //header("Location: ../index.php?Loginn=error3");
        //exit();
}
}
```

Comment: it echoes 1 and then when I refresh the page, the same loginnError3 is shown